# Error while generating Android app

Tags: windev

As on my previous topic, which has been fixed, (http://forum.pcsoft.com/en-US/windevmobile/26508-cle-google-map-lors-generation-application-android-26510/Read.awp), I want to generate an app on WinDev Mobile 22

At the very end, I have these messages

```
Failed to create the Android application <C: \ My Mobile Projects \ My_AndreamProject \ Exe \ My_Project_Android.apk>.


Command line: "C: \ Program Files \ Java \ jdk1.8.0_72 \ bin \ java.exe" "-Dorg.gradle.appname = C: \ My Mobile Projects \ My_Project_Android \ Android \ Generation" -classpath "C: \ Gradle \ lib \ gradle-launcher.jar "org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain assembleDebug -b build.gradle


Returned error:
Org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.UnknownModuleException: Can not locate JAR for 'gradle-launcher' module IN distribution directory 'C: \ gradle'.
At org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry.loadModule (DefaultModuleRegistry.java:108)
At org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry.getModule (DefaultModuleRegistry.java:77)
At org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultClassPathProvider.findClassPath (DefaultClassPathProvider.java:33)
At org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultClassPathRegistry.getClassPath (DefaultClassPathRegistry.java:34)
At org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit (ProcessBootstrap.java:49)
At org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run (ProcessBootstrap.java:37)
At org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main (GradleMain.java:23)
```

And I do not know what to do with it, if you have a solution ..

Comment: Up please, I need help. ^^

Comment: I have not used windows, but I presume you need to download and install gradle OR it should be available locally since studio would have downloaded it. What does a search in that folder yeild?

Answer (score 1):

Solved, just have to install Gradle 2.14.1, not the lasts

Now I have ;

Valid ABIs: no ABIs.
Error: Invalid --abi no for the selected target.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a .jar "C: \ Gradle \ lib \ gradle-launcher.jar " on your computer ?